# Getting right posts on feed from people you follow

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to show all posts from the people I follow on the feed.

I have 3 tables that i'm joining together: users, followers and posts. I see the right people I'm following but with the posts from the user I'm logged in with. So my question is how do I get the right posts with the right user. In my query below I know that I'm joining posts.user_id with the followers Id but if I change this into following I'm getting the followers avatar and name as many times I'm following someone.

My table for followers: [followers][1];

| id | isFollower | isFollowing | status |

My table for posts: [posts][2];

| id | photo | description | location | postedDate | user_id | filter_id |

My table for users: [users][3];

| id | fullName | username |email | password |avatar |bio | dateCreated | isAdmin | isPrivate |

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQqaZ.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzfpx.png [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8O9P.png

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT *, posts.id
FROM posts
  INNER JOIN followers ON posts.user_id = followers.isFollower
  INNER JOIN users ON followers.isFollowing = users.id
where user_id = :userid
```

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the table definitions shown as text instead of as image links. That can make your question easier to read and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a list of posts of people we follow.

To get the list, we need to get the *posts* which have *user_id* equal to those *isFollower* columns in *followers* table, which *isFollowing* column have ID equal to ours.

So, we are joining *posts* with the *followers*, and making *isFollower* column equal to our post's *user_id*, and *isFollowing* equal to our ID.

```
SELECT `posts`.*
FROM `posts`
JOIN `followers` ON (
    `followers`.`isFollower` = `posts`.`user_id` AND
    `followers`.`isFollowing` = :userId
)
```